# How do I secure my Amazon S3 photos but still make them available via URLs?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm planning on making my (family) photo collection available online. I want to use S3 and build an ASP.NET site that will display the photos. I don't want the website to pull down the S3 content and return it to the browser. I want browsers to be able to go directly to S3 without affecting my ASP.NET bandwidth.

It is possible to build URLs for each photo if I set the S3 permission to public, but I only want the photos to be accessible by visitors to my website, not anyone who has the URL.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generate temporary URLs to secured resources on S3.

See the bottom of [S3 Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html)

Comment: I am in similar dilemma so read the link you provided (still valid!). I guess anyone with the pre-signed url can still access the photos. How is it providing more security (unless you set expiration time, which I think original questioner does not want)? As long as I have the url if I can access the content, I don't care if its signed or not. Wouldn't the better approach be to let backend server handle the image retrieval and requests to server is authenticated using web tokens?