# How to send pdf document as a Ruby on Rails Restful Web Service response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

We have all pdf documents located on Amazon S3 and we are trying to develop or expose the restful web services from Ruby on Rails application which returns the response in Json format.

Here we facing issue, how to send pdf document as web service response. Can anybody help me on this ?

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: Hi Chetan. You are more likely to get answered if you add some more details. What have you tried? what fails? Post some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

If talking with your service clients via JSON is crucial for architecture, then - best solution in my opinion is sending direct link to the document, otherwise read PDF and then stream it to client.

Comment: Thanks for quick response on this. Sending a link would not help because document is located on S3. So we will have to send the secret key and access key to devise which is very bad practice. So one solution could be read the pdf document body and covert it into Json format and send it to devise and at other end devise will recreate the document. One major drawback of this approach is file IO operation is very time consuming and which require lot of memory and processing. So devise might hang in this case. Please let me know if anyone have any better solution on this.

Comment: You might generate a temporary link to s3 objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681809/how-do-i-secure-my-amazon-s3-photos-but-still-make-them-available-via-urls

Comment: Amar: No documents required access to S3.

Comment: Can anybody point me to direction how to send pdf document as a response of Restful web service.